# Livereload after save

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I've just started programming in QML using QtCreator. I prefer to write QML files using code editor, not the design editor. But after each save, I have to run the app to see the changes. Even enabling auto-save on build is not a solution, because a new window appears for each build, but old windows are still on the desktop.

So I wrote this two-lines scripts in bash to livereload the UI after saving QML:

```
while sleep 0.1; do qmlscene main.qml; done &
while true; do while inotifywait -e close_write *.qml; do killall qmlscene; done; done &
```

When a QML is saved, `killall qmlscene` is called, then a new `qmlscene` is started.

Does QtCreator provide a livereload feature like this? I don't need to recompile, a reload of qml files should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [`clearComponentCache`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#clearComponentCache), but you will need to reload the qml after calling it:

```
view->engine()->clearComponentCache();
view->setSource("qml/main.qml");
view->show();
```

Comment: I'm looking for an IDE feature, I want to avoid changing code. Something like `qmlscene --watch main.qml`

Comment: No you'll not find any IDE doing that, you will always need to close then open the application or clear and reload  the cache.

Answer (score 0):

V-Play Engine offers QML Live Reloading for Apps and Games, on Windows, Linux, MacOS, iOS and Android.

You can find more info on our blog here:

https://v-play.net/updates/release-2-14-0-live-code-reloading-for-desktop-ios-android

We recently also added live reloading from the browser, to test code examples right from the documentation and blog:

https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/web-editor-test-online-code-examples-on-android-and-ios-with-live-code-reloading